# How to evaluate a static boolean in Spring Security's @PreAuthorize?

Tags: spring-security, spring-el

I have a static boolean provided by a configuration class. Depending on the value of this variable I want to allow or deny access to an endpoint.

The following attempt unfortunately results in a `SpelParseException` (Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'):

```java
@GetMapping({"/registration"})
@PreAuthorize("#{T(com.example.config.ApplicationProperties).REGISTRATION_ENABLE}")

public String registration() {
    //...
}
```

The attempt was to somehow make what works with `@ConditionalOnExpression` also work with `@PreAuthorize`:

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{T(com.example.config.ApplicationProperties).REVEAL_SECRETS}")
public class VerySecretStuff {
    //...
}
```

#### My question is:

Is there a way to access a static variable within a `@PreAuthorize` Spring EL expression and do an evaluation which is then used for the access?

I know that we can utilize the Spring Context and provide a bean which is able to evaluate our needs. But I am looking for a simplier solution, in case one exists.

**Many thanks for any help**

Comment: Try without the `#{...}`; the javadoc says the string should be a SpEL expression. The `#{...}` syntax is used when a String property is a literal and Spring evaluates the expression to a String. Looks like `@COE` doesn't care, but `@PA` doesn't expect it.

Comment: @GaryRussell : perfect, works like charm. Maybe you wanna give your answer in a quick and dirty post, so I can pick it? Anyway, MANY THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the `#{...}`; the javadoc says the string should be a SpEL expression.

The `#{...}` syntax is used when a String property is a literal and Spring evaluates the expression to a String. Looks like `@ConditionalOnExpression`  ignores the delimiters, but `@PreAuthorize`  doesn't expect them.

A bit inconsistent, perhaps, but...

Also, in SpEL ,`#foo` is  reference to a variable `foo` in the evaluation context (which was the hint that the `{` was unexpected).